# Tkinter: How do I build an application for several different screen resolutions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm working on an application in Python with Tkinter as the GUI framework. The first picture is a screenshot from my coworkers computer, the second is a screenshot from my computer. How can I make widgets(buttons, labels, entries, etc) adaptable for any screen resolution?
[image: GUI from Coworkers computer]

[image: GUI from My Computer]

**Sample of my code**

```
self.e_fname = Entry(self)
    self.e_fname.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.18, height=40, relwidth=0.27)
    self.l_fname = Label(self, text='''First Name:''', font=font9,bg='#0066AB')
    self.l_fname.place(relx=0.055, rely=0.13, height=40, width=514)
    # last name
    self.e_lname = Entry(self)
    self.e_lname.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.18, height=40, relwidth=0.27)
    self.l_lname = Label(self, text='''Last Name:''', font=font9,bg='#0066AB')
    self.l_lname.place(relx=0.395, rely=0.13, height=40, width=514)
    # email
    self.e_mail = Entry(self)
    self.e_mail.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.29,height=40, relwidth=0.57)
    self.l_mail = Label(self, text='''Email Address:''', font=font9, bg='#0066AB')
    self.l_mail.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.24, height=31, width=514)
    # phone number
    self.e_phone = Entry(self)
    self.e_phone.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.40, height=40, relwidth=0.57)
    self.l_phone = Label(self, text= '''Phone Number:''', font=font9, bg='#0066AB')
    self.l_phone.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.36, height=31, width=514)
    # Address
    self.e_saddress = Entry(self)
    self.e_saddress.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.51, height=40, relwidth=0.57)
    self.adress = Label(self, text='''Address:''', font=font9, bg='#0066AB')
    self.adress.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.46, height=31, width=514)
    # Address Line 2
    self.e_saddress2 = Entry(self)
    self.e_saddress2.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.62, height=40, relwidth=0.57)
    self.adress2 = Label(self, text='''Address Confirmation:''', font=font9, bg='#0066AB')
    self.adress2.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.57, height=31, width=514)
    # State
    self.state = Label(self, text='''State:''', font=font9, bg='#0066AB')
```

Comment: use the `fill` and `expand` parameters of the `pack()` method, or the `grid()` equivalents. Only use `place()` for **special** situations, this is not one of them. Use `ttk` and set a custom style Label.

Comment: How do you define "adaptable"?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Keeping the same layout on different sized monitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to make a UI retain its layout on systems with different resolutions and different font sizes is to use `grid` and `pack` instead of `place`. `place` is really only good for very specific types of problems, and responsiveness isn't it's strong suite.

In your specific case it looks like it would be a good idea to use `grid` since your widgets appear to be laid out in rows and columns. When using `grid`, take care to take advantage of all of the options, especially the `sticky` attribute. Also, make sure that you take advantage of the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` methods to give some or all of your rows and columns a non-zero weight so that extra space is allocated to them.

Comment: Thank you so much!